# bunsenlabs helium synaptics touchpad exists in system but doesn't work

Tags: touchpad, 32bit, bunsenlabs

I just install bunsenlabs helium 32bit on my old machine.

- TOSHIBA NB520 w/ INTEL ATOM INSIDE and 2GB RAM

Unfortunately the touchpad does not work propertly. Indeed it doesn't work at all.

I have installed all drivers and system "see" that device:

```
me@toshiba-nb520:~$ xinput | grep TouchPad
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad          id=17     [slave pointer (2)]
```

But when i try to use `xinput test 17`, there is nothing.

```
me@toshiba-nb520:~$ xinput test 17
^C
me@toshiba-nb520:~$
```

I've tried different solutions, but none have made the cursor come alive ...

**Does this mean that the touchpad is broken and will not work?**

*The last time I used my computer a few months ago, the touchpad worked on windows and linux. I had to decide to change the system and test the helium because the distributions that I used worked very slowly on this computer. Helium is the first system to run smoothly on that old (----) machine, and I'd like to use it.*